# Laravel Array being displayed all together, I want one by one

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
@foreach($carServices as $item)                                   
         <div class="d-inline me-2">
                <h5>
                     @php 
                         $s_Items = implode("", $item->services_list);
                         echo $s_Items . "<br>";
                     @endphp                                                                                                
                </h5>
         </div>
@endforeach
```

Result: Service 1,  Service 2, Service 3

Comment: Do you mean "explode" and not "implode"?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, implode joins an array. In your case, it seems like it's joining the $item->services_list.

You should use explode instead.

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Example:

```
@foreach($carServices as $item)                                   
     <div class="d-inline me-2">
            <h5>
                 @foreach(explode(",", $item->services_list) as $sub_item) 
                     $sub_item <br>
                 @endforeach                                                                                                
            </h5>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Does not display individual array items, displays the $sub_item variable

Comment: Can you show what data you have in $carServices or at least the form that it's in.

For this to work, you would need an array (carServices) of strings ($item->services_list) that are comma separated. 

Without seeing how the data is structured, it's hard to help.

Comment: CarService: [id], [car_id], [services_list]-> long text, cast array Laravel

Comment: if $item->services_list is already an array, why not just iterate through it? i.e. @foreach($item->services_list as $sub_item) ? (Se não, se calhar não percebi bem o que vc queria dizer com "long text, cast array Laravel". Se for um texto, mostra-me o texto sff)